# Benefits of .each() function in jQuery over traditional "for" loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of my colleague suggested me to use jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) function over javascript `for` loop to traverse through `DOM` elements on my page, I am not a newbie in jQuery, but never understood the real reason behind why developers tend to use `.each()` over for loop of javascript. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Because it is shorter and doesn't explicitly define any extra variables.

Comment: And because you can chain it to a selector!

Comment: it is more readable, than for loop !

Comment: and you can pass it a function :) so you could wrap it in another function and pass your each function to the wrapper

Comment: @Luke Which creates a new scope/closure for every iteration, which is usually good :)

Comment: ... and also because you can use `this` to refer the current element.

Comment: @VisioN By "doesn't explicitly define any extra variables", do you mean that it doesn't define any variables (like the iterator) that pollute the current scope?

Comment: @Ian Yes if that also implies `var i = 0; ...` :)

Comment: If performance matters to you, then have a look at http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/73 and http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/

Comment: The question is how one programming technique compares to another one. What on Earth is "not constructive" about that?

Comment: See performance comparison http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/24

Comment: One more benefit people often overlook is **method chaining**. I use it a **lot** (although usually I would place the `.each()` as the last call on the chain, it just feels more readable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to iterate using a `for` loop, you have to increment the index:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
```

and then you have to get the actual value using the index:

```
var value = arr[i];
```

`.each` does both of these for you and passes the values into a function:

```
$(...).each(function(i, value) {
    // actual interesting part of the loop...
});
```

It simply saves you the boilerplate code of incrementing the index and getting the value at that index.

The variables defined in an `.each` function are also closed over (i.e., within a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)), so the equivalent code (considering looping and variable closure, plus setting `this`, as well as breaking on a `false` return value) might be something like:

```
(function() {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {

        var ret = (function(index, value) {
            // actual interesting part of the loop...
        }).call(arr[i], i, arr[i]);

        if(ret === false) break;
    }
})();
```

which is quite a bit more to type.

In terms of execution performance, `.each` is (unsurprisingly) slower than a raw `for` loop, because it does much more than a raw `for` loop.

Comment: The closure in your last snippet only closes over the loop, not over the body - which is essential for using IEFEs in loops :-)

Comment: Yep, anonymous function must be used inside `for` loop with passing `i` or `arr[i]` to it.

Comment: @Bergi Right, of course, whoops! So there should be two IIFEs, one outside the loop (to prevent `i` from reaching the outer namespace) and one within it to preserve index and value for each iteration.

Comment: And not to be a stickler, but technically, if the anonymous function returns false, the loop should break. Haha probably not too important

Comment: @apsillers thanks for explanation, but this test contradicts with what you're saying: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/214

Comment: @Sam Which of my statements in particular does this test contradict? Your test doesn't even include the code I've suggested, so I'm not really sure what you think is being contradicted here. Are you objecting to the fact that I didn't set `this` appropriately? (I've edited to include that.)

Comment: @apsillers Sorry I thought you were proving that .each() is better as far as performance goes, but it's not the case based on http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/214 Can you please explain why .each() is having poor performance, I am just trying to know why .each() is better or even if it is better or not at the first place?

Comment: @Sam The short answer is: *`.each` is slower than a raw `for` loop because it does much more than a raw `for` loop*, which is, of course, totally unsurprising.

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy to use

But it is slow as shown in this test result. 
http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/214

Comment: Strictly speaking, speed difference mostly defends loops than `.each()` method. But the question is *why `.each()` is better*.

Comment: Baadshah, seems like it contradicts your statement as well as my colleague http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/214

Comment: @Sam actually my intention is to say that its easy to use but slow.

Comment: @VisioN Sorry for the mass confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is easier & cleaner to do

```
$jqExpr.each(function(i, el){
   /* YOUR CODE */
});

than

for(var i=0; i < $jqQExpr.length; i++){
  el = $jqExp[i];
  /* YOUR CODE */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's slower, but more expressive (shorter) and it also sets up closures. Also, on jQuery collections it integrates well into chaining; while for plain arrays I would suggest using the native [`.forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: You could still use `jQuery.each` to iterate over arrays/objects (instead of `forEach`). I know you said "suggest", so I'm just saying that's the jQuery option (for whoever reads this)

Comment: Sure, `$.each(arr, fn)` is for those who don't want to shim `arr.forEach(fn)`. Yet, it's less OOP style and slower, so I don't see a reason to use it. (And for those who don't know: Don't use `$(arr).each(fn)` on plain arrays!)

Comment: It may be "less OOP style", but in what languages is there a method to iterate over an array's contents? The norm is a `for` loop (or some `while` loop and/or a real iterator), so there's nothing wrong with `$.each` as it's just a wrapper for it. I understand and agree `forEach` is "faster" or "better", but a normal `for` loop would be fine anyways. And `$(arr).each(fn)` works fine for arrays....all it does is internally call `$.each()`...`[1, 2, 3]` is no different from `[DOMElement, DOMElement, DOMElement]` in terms of looping.

Answer (score 0):

There is also, for me, an important benefit closure side effect if you use each instead of for.

Consider the code below (I'm using coffeescript as I'm found of..) which alerts on all links with its href value:

```
$("a").each (i, e)->
  href = $(e).attr('href')
  $(e).on "click" alert(href)
```

If you "translate" it into a simple for loop like :

```
for e in $("a")
  href = $(e).attr('href')
  $(e).on "click" alert(href)
```

This code won't work as the href variable is not enclosed in a closure...